# how to change color of background, row , row selection and header in angular 4 with bootstrap 4 data-table

Tags: css, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

I have implemented bootstrap 4 data table 4 in  angular 4 but not able to change or modify row color. row selection color and header color as well.

I am using the data table 4 example : https://github.com/afermon/angular-4-data-table-bootstrap-4

and in this examples demo go through the demo 1 of link: https://afermon.github.io/angular-4-data-table-bootstrap-4-demo/

Comment: Please provide HTML+CSS code

Comment: take a look at this maybe it helps. https://datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4.html  , also you could use noraml `css` to style and target the row, text or header?

Comment: You can see the demo code in their Github repository: https://github.com/afermon/angular-4-data-table-bootstrap-4-demo

Comment: Thanks for your comment @DGarvanski, but in that demo no such custom styling are given.

Comment: Are their CSS files not what your looking for? Something like this one they have: `:host /deep/ .data-table .data-table-row.selected {background-color:#E4EDF9;}` ?

Comment: yes @DGarvanski I have write something like `table .data-table-row.selected {background-color:#E4EDF9;} && table.dataTable thead th{
    background-color: #e2e2e2;
    font-size: 18px;
     line-height: 1.43;
     text-align: left;
     color: grey;
  } ` in our css but it is not overriding.

Comment: I know its not the way to go, but have you tried `!important` just to see if the css is working or picking up your changes, could be cached?

Answer (score 1):

Considering the below code snippet present in **data-table-component-demo1.ts** got by the Git project you downloaded:

```
<data-table id="persons-grid"
        [header] = "false"
        [multiSelect] = "false"
        [substituteRows]="false"
        [indexColumn]="false"
        [items]="items"
        [itemCount]="itemCount"
        (reload)="reloadItems($event)"
        [pagination]="false"        
        (rowClick)="rowClick($event)"
        [rowColors] = "callBackForChangineRowColors" 
        >
        <data-table-column 
            [property]="'name'"
            [header]="'Name'"            
            [sortable]="true"
            [styleClass]="someExplicitClass"
```

1. In this, we can assign the value 'someExplicitClass' to [styleClass] as shown above and define the class someExplicitClass in our **data-table-component-demo1.css** file as below:

   :host /deep/ .someExplicitClass{
       background-color:red;
       }

   However, this is applied to the whole of the DataColumn and not controllable on a granular level.
2. We can indirectly apply only background-color using the rowEvent variable available within the rowClick(rowEvent) function of **'data-table-component-demo1.ts'**

   On click of the row, I will set the selected property of the row to true and thereby will trigger the onRowSelectChanged function of table.component.ts file

Now, once I set [rowColors] value to "callBackForChangineRowColors" as shown above and make the below changes in my **data-table-component-demo1.component.ts** file:

```
rowClick(rowEvent) {
        console.log('Clicked: ' + rowEvent.row.item.name);
        rowEvent.row.selected = true;        
    }

    callBackForChangineRowColors(a,b,c)
    {
        if(b.selected)
        return 'blue';
    }
```

This way, I will be able to apply the color of blue explicitly for the selected Row.

*I could'nt unfortunately find any solution to apply any other styles on a granular level using a readily available input parameter like [styleClass] for it wasnt exposed as an @Input within our column.component.ts. If anyone has an idea, please do help me know it.